# Bug: Slider Appearing Every time using viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slider

i am making a slider walkthrough which is introduced in the app for the first item when the user clicks the app....and it is gone when the user again open it.

like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=va2IRW_e7_w

the problem is that i am regaining it again and again whenever i opent the app, its a small mistake and i can't find it.

Main2Activity:

```
    public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

        Button next, skip;
        private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
        private ViewPager viewPager;
        private SliderWalkthrough sliderWalkthrough;
        private int[] layouts;
        private TextView[] dots;
        private LinearLayout dotsLayout;

ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            addButtonDots(position);
            if (position == layouts.length - 1) {

                next.setText("GET STARTED");
                skip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                next.setText("NEXT");
                skip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    };

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            sliderWalkthrough = new SliderWalkthrough(this);
            if (!sliderWalkthrough.Check()) {
                sliderWalkthrough.setFirst(false);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {

                getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

            }
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.id_WalkThroughViewPager);
            dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_dots);

            layouts = new int[]{R.layout.slider_walkthrough_screen1, R.layout.slider_walkthrough_screen2, R.layout.slider_walkthrough_screen3};
            addButtonDots(0);

            adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter();
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(listener);

        }

        private void addButtonDots(int position) {

            dots = new TextView[layouts.length];
            int[] colorActive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.active_dot);
            int[] colorInactive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.inactive_dot);
            dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
            for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                dots[i] = new TextView(this);
                dots[i].setTextSize(30);
                dots[i].setTextColor(colorInactive[position]);
                dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);

            }
            if (dots.length > 0) {
                dots[position].setTextColor(colorActive[position]);
            }

        }
    }
```

SliderWalkthrough:

```
public class SliderWalkthrough {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context context;

    public SliderWalkthrough(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences("first",0);
        editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
     }

    public void setFirst(Boolean firstTime){
        editor.putBoolean("check",firstTime);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean Check()
    {
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("check",true);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your `listener`'s code `viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(listener);`?

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh i haven't pasted it because its of no use what my problem deals with

Comment: i asked you , cuz it's relevant , in short you need to call `setFirst(false)` when you are done with your view pager slides not inside `if (!sliderWalkthrough.Check()) {`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh i have pasted the code help me out but still i didn't get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `preference` value to `false` once your walk-through is finished otherwise `if (!sliderWalkthrough.Check()) {` will never be executed and walk-through will be shown everytime

```
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        addButtonDots(position);
        if (position == layouts.length - 1) {
            next.setText("GET STARTED");
            skip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            sliderWalkthrough.setFirst(false);
            //^^^^^^ add this case
        } 
         else {
            next.setText("NEXT");
            skip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Note : remove `sliderWalkthrough.setFirst(false);` , no longer required

```
        if (!sliderWalkthrough.Check()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
```

Comment: i got it a little , just a little logic , try the updated code , surely work

Comment: explanation of issue is same , `layouts.length - 1` mean case `2` to change the preference state once you reach the last page of your walk-thorough . i am glad that i could help